# Pycharm sometimes does not indent the proper amount

Tags: python, pycharm

I have `tabs and indents|indent` set to 2:

[image]

However the actual indentation is coming up as 3 - specifically inside the `groupby` function - which I have unindented and re-indented several times to be sure the behavior were consistent[*-ly incorrect*]:

[image]

Note that I have also tried the `Auto-indent` (`Option-Command-I`) - it *also* indents stuff to 3 spaces instead of 2. Bit strange..

Any thoughts?

Comment: I see you've tried Option+Command+I (Auto Indent), but have you tried Option+Command+L (Reformat Code)?

Comment: @AndroidNoobie  `reformat code` _does_ do the job.. Any idea why is the indention line-by-line messed up?

Comment: Oh this is interesting:  now the indention behavior is working. So you seem to have bumped into a workaround:  just ensure that _at least once_ to run _reformat code_. Seems to get the file in the right "mindset" moving forward.

Comment: @AndroidNoobie  pls add an answer - and include my observations within

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The first thing you might want to check is to make sure you don't have **Detect and use existing file indents for editing** enabled in `Settings/Preferences | Editor | Code Style`. If you do, when you auto-indent, it might apply the wrong settings.

You can try to fix incorrectly formatted code by using `Option+Command+L` (Mac) / `Control+Alt+L` (PC), which is the **Reformat Code** option. That should fix the code and then auto-indent should work correctly.

Comment: This was exactly what I needed and have been searching for forever. Great answer, thanks.

Comment: I had "Detect and use..." enabled, but also had to disable EditorConfig. No idea what that is, but this answer plus that worked.

Answer (score 1):

This is most annoying problem in pycharm. Here is simple answer to this :

Just follow the path :

GO to **Edit**->**Convert Indents**->**To Spaces**

This will actually insert space instead of tabular character in empty space when you default enter for next line.